# Reclassifying based on neighbour polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, classification

I have a polygon shapefile and each one has one class attached. I want to reclassify one of them based in the neighbours.

For example, I have a polygon with class street and I want to reclassify to a house if one of the polygons around it (or one that contains it) belong to class urbanization in QGIS.

Comment: I guess this is what you are talking about: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40898/calculate-polygon-field-based-on-neigboring-polygon-attribute