# How could I assess the value of a polygon according to the value of his neighbor?

Tags: qgis, vector

I would like to know if it is possible to give a value to a polygon, according to the value of the polygons around.

I want to assess the ecological integrity of an aquatic network (lakes, pond, streams, rivers, etc.), where each features is assessed independently. For example, one of the criteria is the dominant riparian land cover. According to the kind of land cover, the integrity of a lake would vary.

I already have the vector of the hydrological network and the vectors of the riparian land cover around each feature of the hydrological network. Note that the composition of the riparian land cover is not homogenous around the lake.

How can I use QGIS to do this?

Comment: So, just to clarify- you have two separate polygon layers representing water features and land cover types (non-intersecting). And you wish to attribute each polygon of the water feature layer with the land cover type value that is most prevalent in its neighbouring land cover polygons?

Comment: Yes that's exaclty what I want to do

Comment: Or calculate the mean value of the polygone around the water feature and then attribut this value to the water featers itself. If it is possible

Comment: Definitely possible- the challenge to overcome is that one-to-many spatial joins in QGIS are a little convoluted. I can try and come up with a solution but as I'm primarily an ArcGIS user there are others who would likely be able to develop much more elegant QGIS solutions. Is the land cover value a string (Grass, Sparse vegetation etc.) or just a number representing a land cover type? It will make things much easier if it's a numeric value.

Comment: Yes it is a numeric value ! I've also learn GIS with ArcGis first... so if you explain the solution with ArcGis method, I should be able to find my way with Qgis.

Comment: In researching this I came across this question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40898/calculate-polygon-field-based-on-neigboring-polygon-attribute) which basically outlines all the ArcGIS steps you need in the second answer (from GIS-Jonathan). There are also some QGIS based solutions there so hopefully that helps as well. Good luck!